# Random Number Generator with no repeats

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to work out how to make a random number generator that outputs 4 integers going from 0 to 9 without any repeats.

[image]

Would like some help please
i have just started coding in c# but cant find any answers to my issue

Comment: RNG without repeats - another way of saying that is that you want a **shuffle** (and then just consume as many items from the start of that as you need). You may have better luck looking for that term.

Comment: please post the direct code and not pictures of it

Comment: Random rand = new Random();
            int[] randNumbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new { n = x, rand = rand.Next() }).OrderBy(x => x.rand).Select(x => x.n).ToArray();

Comment: This is being made in c#, Console, Visual Studio

Comment: OT if you want to re-assign a value, you must not repeat the type (as that would try and create a new variable with the same name as an existing one - therefore the red squigglies). So just `val2 = rnd.Next...`

Comment: [Why not upload images of code when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

For "quick and dirty" solution you can use [`LINQ`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/). For example something like this will randomly select 4 numbers in range from 0 to 9:

```cs
var random = new Random();
var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)
    .OrderBy(_ => random.Next())
    .Take(4)
    .ToList();
```

In case you need something more prescise and faster then you can implement [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for example.

Comment: This has a bias for items earlier in the range being more likely.

Comment: @Servy can you please explain?

Comment: OrderBy is a stable sort, so items earlier in the collection will be earlier in the results in the event of a collision.

Comment: Obviously this solution is also much less efficient than an actual shuffle algorithm, in addition to not actually being evenly distributed.

Comment: And of course posting answers to frequently asked questions is inappropriate.  You should be voting to close as a duplicate.

Comment: @Servy thank you for the information. Also I would say bias (despite definetely being present) should be quite small.

Comment: And yet still there.  And given that writing the code that is *actually* random, and performs better, is super simple and widely available, there's just no reason not to use that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the `int` from the checking if it has already repeated.
so:

```
if (val1 == val2)
{
    val2 = rnd.Next(1,11);
}
```

and not:

```
if (val1 == val2)
{
    int val2 = rnd.Next(1,11);
}
```

The latter will declare a new variable "val2" which exists only inside the scope of the "if" block, instead of updating the existing "val2" variable as you intended. This is called "shadowing".

Comment: That's actually a compile error in this case.

Comment: Removing this compiler error doesn't result in code that actually works though.